# View model alternative for many-to-many relationship

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, many-to-many

In ASP.NET and Entity Framework, I have a many-to-many relationship for user and classroom. I'm trying to get a list of students in a class. So far I know 2 solutions: create a user/class view model, or pass around a `ViewBag.ClassId` between controller and view.

Is there a way for a view page that use

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.User>
```

to get info from `Model.Class` without creating a new view model?

I'm used to java jsp where I can pass any kind of variable, so I'm new to this view/model restriction.

(The user and class model are scaffolded from the database with table "userclass" as a join table).

So far I've just been passing a `viewbag.classId` to every controller and make that the parameter:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ClassStudents(int id)
{
    var usersInClass = await _context.Classes
                        .Where(cls => cls.Id == id)
                        .Include(cls => cls.Users) // Eager loading to load associated users
                        .Select(cls => cls.Users.Where(user => user.RoleSettingId == 5))
                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    ViewBag.ClassId = id;

    return View("/Views/Classroom/ClassStudents.cshtml", usersInClass);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve here? Seems like you found the way to get it to work. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `User` and `Classroom` class has already configured many to many relationships, you can use Navigation properties to display the class information from the Model.User.
Refer to the following sample:

My models:

```cs
public class User
{
     public int ID { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public IList<Classroom> Classrooms { get; set; } = new List<Classroom>();
}

public class Classroom
{
     [Key]
     public int CID { get; set; }

     public string CName { get; set; }
     public IList<User> User { get; set; } = new List<User>();
}
```

My dbcontext：

```cs
    public SchoolDbcontext(DbContextOptions<SchoolDbcontext> options)
    : base(options) { }
    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Classroom> Classrooms { get; set; }
            
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
         modelBuilder.Entity<Classroom>().HasMany(x => x.User).WithMany(st => st.Classrooms);
    }
```

Controller:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> ClassStudentsAsync(int id)
{
    var classnum = _context.Classrooms.Include(x=>x.User).FirstOrDefault(cls => cls.CID == id);
    var stu = new List<User>();
    for (var i = 0; i < classnum.User.Count; i++)
    {
        var students = classnum.User[i];
        stu.Add(students);
    }
    return View(stu);
}
```

My CSHTML:

```html
@using WebApplication1.Models
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.User>

<h1>Student List</h1>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Student ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>ClassName</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var user in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@user.ID</td>
                <td>@user.Name</td>
                <td>@user.Classrooms.FirstOrDefault().CName</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I give class id: 2

[image: Output]

Besides, about the query statement, you can check the following statement:
The result is a list of User.

In my sample code, the `User` and `ClassRooms` are configured many to many relationship and the `UserClass` is the join table.

```cs
var userlist = _dbContext.ClassRooms.Where(c => c.ClassID == id)
                            .Include(cls => cls.UserClass.Where(c => c.ClassId == id)) // Eager loading to load associated users
                            .ThenInclude(uc => uc.User)
                            .SelectMany(cls => cls.UserClass.Select(c=>c.User)).ToList();

var userlist2 = _dbContext.User.Include(u => u.UserClass.Where(c=>c.ClassId == id))
                               .ThenInclude(c=>c.ClassRoomes).Where(cls => cls.UserClass.Any(c => c.ClassId == id)).ToList();
```